# WP Parse Enclosure url

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, rss

i recently made an app using windows app studio online, and suprisingly the app turn out alright it handles the rss feeds quite nicely. Ive made some changes to the app, as the feed contains a enclosure url which is a download link. i cant get it to detect the enclosure url. i think im just expressing it wrong.

i tried every online rss source viewer to see if it appeared any different in yahoo pipes it appears as item.enclosure.url, on code beauty it appears as http://bla.com"/> ive tried every combination i can think of

i also tried putting the feed through yahoo pipes to give me a new feed with the enclosure url in a new tag
        < downloadlink >< /downloadlink> and used the code

```
rssItem.FeedUrl = item.GetSafeElementString("downloadlink")
```

and the whole app works as it should so i know the only thing im doing wrong is retieving the enclosure url the only problem with yahoo pipes is you cant change the input url which i need to do so it has to come from the enclosure url

so my question is how should i retrieve the tag

```
rssItem.FeedUrl = item.GetSafeElementString("whatgoeshere")
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked Nicely

```
        XElement element = item.Element("enclosure"); //new element

        int length = (int)element.Attribute("length"); //seprate attributes
        string type = (string)element.Attribute("type");
        string url = (string)element.Attribute("url");

        rssItem.FeedUrl = url; // use the result
```